# Deriving a formula in terms of slopes of an angle between two oblique lines

Tags: calculus

Two oblique lines intersect at the origin, both passing through the first quadrant. Let the angle in the first quadrant between the lines be $\theta$. Derive an appropriate formula for finding this angle in terms of the slope of the lines.

So I'm not sure what to do to derive a formula.

Comment: With the title of this question I learned that amalgamating the phrase "Deriving a formula" into one word is "Dracula". Indeed it was strange to see a question titled "Dracula in terms of slopes". :-)

Comment: Here's a hint: you can assume that they pass through the origin (because the relative angle won't change). The only information you have then is slopes so your angle should be a function of _only_ the slopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  the slopes are the tangents of the angles to the $x$ axis.

Added:  here is a picture with 10 and 30 degree lines.  The angle between them is 20 degrees

[image]

Comment: Oh, so are u trying to say that I can use the 2 other angles formed and somehow use pie/2 or 90 degrees in my formula?

Comment: No, I was giving the relationship between the slopes and the angles.  How do you get from the tangent of an angle to the angle itself?

Comment: the inverse tangent?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Now you have the two angles with respect to the $x$ axis.  What next?

Comment: I'm not sure, but does it have something to do with the slope of the x axis being 0?

Comment: You are looking for the angle between the two lines.  If you have the angles with respect to something (here, the $x$ axis), subtract them.

Comment: 90- theta2-theta3= theta1?

Comment: Why the 90? If one line is 10 degrees up from $x$ and the other is 30 degrees up, wouldn't the angle between them be 20 degrees?  Note that you need a positive answer.

Comment: oh I was thinking since the angle is in the first quadrant, it has to be between 0 and 90. I understand what you're saying but how can I find the angle

Comment: To be in the first quadrant, each angle will be between $0$ and $90$. When you subtract them, you will again get something between $0$ and $90$. What is wrong with $30-10=20?$

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?

Comment: yes I have drawn a picture, and I wasn't saying anything was wrong with that. I'm bad with problems like this